# Jquery Not Grabbing Value from Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to manipulate the values in a form field after a `click` event with Jquery, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to grab anything from the form, and I don't think it's the jQuery syntax, since I use it successfully elsewhere in the program.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="centered formula-form">
  <input type="text" id="project" name="project" placeholder="Name your project"  maxlength="20" required />
  <input type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Give it a brief description"  maxlength="35" required /> <br /> <br />
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ingredient Name" required  />
  <input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="0" min="0" step="0.1" required />
  <input type="text" id="notes" placeholder="form, supplier, etc" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Ingredient" class="pure-button" />
</form>

<table class="centered-block pure-table pure-table-striped formula-table">
  <thead class="thead-styled">
    <tr class="centered">
        <th>Ingredient</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="formula-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary formula-submit" >Submit</button>
```

When `button class="formula-submit"` is clicked I'm trying save the form values like so:

**JQuery:**

```
$('.formula-submit').click(function(){
  //declare variables
  var projectName = $('#project').val();
  var description = $('#description').val();
});
```

But this hasn't worked.  I've also tried:

```
$('input:text[name=project]').val()
```

But no dice.

As far as I can tell these selectors should work, and what's even more strange to me is that in the same file I make an `AJAX` call that uses the `$('#project').val()` convention and it works just fine, so I'm not sure what it is about the structure of my code that's prohibiting me from getting these values.

I've done `console.log` to verify that jQuery is actually recording the click event and it is.

Comment: Works for me pretty well

Comment: me too...make sure it's not caching...try closing your browser fully reopening and opening a new private browsing window

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem you're having is. I haven't really changed your code, but if you run the snippet below, add some text in the `#projectName` and `#description` fields and click submit, it console.logs them out. Is that what you're trying to do?

```js
$('.formula-submit').click(function(){
  var projectName = $('#project').val();
  var description = $('#description').val(); 
  console.log( `Your projectName is ${projectName}` );
  console.log( `Your description is ${description}` );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="centered formula-form">
  <input type="text" id="project" name="project" placeholder="Name your project"  maxlength="20" required />
  <input type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Give it a brief description"  maxlength="35" required /> <br /> <br />
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ingredient Name" required  />
  <input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="0" min="0" step="0.1" required />
  <input type="text" id="notes" placeholder="form, supplier, etc" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Ingredient" class="pure-button" />
</form>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary formula-submit" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realize what it was.

There is nothing wrong with the code in my answer.  The problem is that I was referencing the same form values in another file and was emptying the form fields after I passed their data into the `AJAX` call that was being triggered by the same event.

That file was listed above the code in this question so it was being executed first, so by the time I was trying to store the values in the form fields they were already deleted.

Comment: One way to avoid that in the futute is to listen for the `submit` event (instead of click) and then use `var values = $(this).serialize();` to make sure you are only grabing the values from inside that form. http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/